# Is it possible to read multiple csv files with same header or subset of header in same or different order into spark data frame?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I have many csv files in a folder to be loaded into spark data frame. They all have either same header or a header which is a subset of the longest header but in different order.

- File 1 header - `"a","b","c"`
- File 2 header - `"b","c","a"`
- File 3 header - `"a","b"`

I have a schema that has `a,b,c` fields. I am trying to read using

```
sqlcontext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("delimiter",",")
  .option("header","true")
  .load("file*.csv")
```

Is it possible to read multiple csv files with same header or subset of header in same or different order into spark data frame? Instead of editing file to add or change column order I want to handle it in spark.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?
I am looking for something similar.

Comment: I have the exact same problem to solve. In the data directory, new csvs gets added and spark job read the directory. The new csvs can have few more columns changing the order too for existing columns. I want to handle this in spark and accommodate new fields or ignore those fields somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build one dataframe for each kind of structures. 
Say

- DF1 for header "a","b","c"
- DF2 for header "b","c","a"
- DF3 for header "a","b"

Programmatically read the first headers of each file and place it in different directories based on similar headers.

```
DF1 = sqlcontext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter",",").option("header","true").load("DIRECTORY1/file*.csv")
DF2 = sqlcontext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter",",").option("header","true").load("DIRECTORY2/file*.csv")  
DF3 = sqlcontext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter",",").option("header","true").load("DIRECTORY3/file*.csv")
....
```

Final dataframe:

```
DF = DF1.select("a", "b","c").union.DF2.select("a","b","c").union.DF3.select("a","b","")
```

Final dataframe DF can be used for further program logic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In my case all the files are there in the same directory. If I am not aware of which file will have which header format is there a way to load them ?

Comment: you can read files in LOOP and load each file in a dataframe, later you can union all these dataframes based on common fields.

Comment: @ArvindKumar This would work but sounds to be too much of an expensive operation. Any better way to handle this?

Comment: @AkshatChaturvedi - Option 1 We can merge files using Python or any other programming language as pre-processing then create DF on the merged file for further processing.                                                                                                                                                                          Option 2: In loop read files and keep inserting to some temp table and create DF on temp table for further processing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try .option("mergeSchema", "true"). It worked for me.

Comment: This will not work for CSV files